# Dim value disappears vb.net

Tags: vb.net, code-behind

I'm trying to store a value in code behind so I don't have to clog my page with HiddenFields, but the value 'disappears'

I'm assuming it has to do with either scope or byval vs byref, but I don't know how I need to do it for it to work.

What I've tried to do is creating a Dim under my Partial Class, setting the value in a gridview.RowCommand, and then trying to get the value at a later button.Click

```
Partial Class CustNSSF_MinSide
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim vr As New vrClass
Dim _ActNo As String

Sub GV_Relations_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GV_Relations.RowCommand
  _ActNo = GV_Relations.DataKeys(index)("ActSeqNo")

 Protected Sub btn_lagre_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_lagre.Click
            Dim test = _ActNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value disappears because all variables (or controls) are disposed at the end of every page's life-cycle. `GV_Relations_RowCommand` is triggered only on `RowCommand` and `btn_lagre_Click` is a different action. You could store this value in a `Session` variable, `ViewState` or (as you've done) in a `HiddenField`. So when the user clicked on `btn_lagre`, the previous action that caused `RowCommand` was a different postback, therefore the variable is `Nothing`.

So one way (apart from your `HiddenField` aproach), using `ViewState`:

```
Private Property ActSeqNo As System.Int32
    Get
        If ViewState("ActSeqNo") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("ActSeqNo") = System.Int32.MinValue
        End If
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("ActSeqNo"), System.Int32)
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Int32)
        ViewState("ActSeqNo") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then you can set it in this way:

```
Me.ActSeqNo = System.Int32.Parse(GV_Relations.DataKeys(index)("ActSeqNo")))
```

[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in  ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Comment: My boss is not a fan of Session and I feel like HiddenField is probably easier than ViewState. But at least I know why it isn't working and that's really all I needed I guess. Saves me time in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be clear every `Postback`. You need to store it either in the `Viewstate` or in the `Session`. You could do this:

```
Property _ActNo As String 
    Get 
        Return ViewState("_ActNo")
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("_ActNo") = value
    End Set 
End Property
```